# Qt doesn't show database from sql in tableView

Tags: postgresql, qt

Following code creates empty TableView, qInfo()<<currentCV.lastError(); doesn't show any errors.

```
    if(db->open())
{
    QSqlTableModel currentCV;
    currentCV.setTable("employee_skills");
    QTableView *view = new QTableView;
    view->setModel(&currentCV);
    view->show();
    qInfo()<<currentCV.lastError();
}
```

Comment: You have put nowhere in your model that you are using `db`

Comment: I added this
QSqlTableModel qwe;
qwe = new QSqlTableModel(this, *db);

but error says: no viable overloaded '='

Comment: Figured out it's should be

QSqlTableModel *qwe;
qwe = new QSqlTableModel(this, *db);

Comment: And as I think this will still show no data, of course, you have checked in the Qt assistant the definition of `QSqlTableModel::setTable` to understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Worked

```
if(db->open())
{
    QSqlTableModel *model;
    model = new QSqlTableModel(this, *db);
    model->setTable("cv");
    model->select();
    ui->tableView->show();
    ui->tableView->setModel(model);
}
```